# How to update an Aurora Serverless MySQL cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora, aws-aurora-serverless

AWS has announced a "generally available" update for Aurora Serverless MySQL v1 cluster in their documentation:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Updates.serverless_2_08_03.html

However, when creating a new DB cluster, only the existing 2.07.1 version is available. I cannot find any option to update to 2.08.3.

The CLI lists 2.07.1 only:

```
aws rds describe-db-engine-versions --engine aurora-mysql --query 'DBEngineVersions[?contains(SupportedEngineModes,`serverless`)].EngineVersion'
```

output:

```
[
    "5.7.mysql_aurora.2.07.1"
]
```

The same is true for MySQL 5.6:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Updates.serverless_1_22_03.html